# What do you call the part of reality that's not material or physical?

Tags: metaphysics

What do you call the part of reality that's not material or physical? I want to avoid this discussion to be outside of "modern" or "contemporary" metaphysics, so no answer relating to Socrates or other classical Greek philosophers. By physical, I mean everything that can be a subject of scientific inquiry, so anything related to quantum physics would be considered in the physical realm. Was there any discussion on the other part of reality?

Comment: Immaterial and non-physical. If you want a more specific label you need to be more specific as to what part of reality you have in mind, and how it is supposed to manifest. Ideal, abstract, mental, spiritual are some specific candidates that are discussed.

Comment: You should teach yourself the art of [gedankenexperiment](https://www.britannica.com/science/Gedankenexperiment) and take the all spiritual literature of this world. There are many spiritual ontologies and practices with which you can experiment and see the results. That's how Einstein got insights into the nature of space and time and formulated his Theory of Relativity.

Comment: You seem to be presuming some kind of substance dualism. In modern physics only property dualism remains, with information & mass-energy as fundamental, & a firm belief in a unity of substance. Alternatives that there have been are generally now footnotes, or pejoratives.

Comment: @CriglCragl Platonism (i.e. idealism) still has currency among physicists, Tegmark is a platonist as are other ToE enthusiasts. And many analytic philosophers believe in [abstract objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/), which is also a form of platonism.